Verify in Python created digital signature (library rsa, SHA256, PKS1) using Dart (PointyCastle)
`Hello everyone!
I have the following problem: For a project I need to digitally encrypt data (a string) in Python and verify the digital signature in Dart (Flutter). My approach so far:
Python: Library 'rsa' , keypair in PEM format created with OpenSSL

PKS#1 version 1.5
hash method SHA-256

Dart: Library PointyCastle with, as far as I know, the same configuration (PKS1 and SHA-256)
Unfortunately, I just can't get my signature created in Python to be checked in Dart. When I try to convert the signatures into the same format, I always get the result that they do not match.
Does anyone have an idea? Or an alternative solution?
Thank you very much in advance!! :))
Python Code:
import rsa

private_key_data = b'''-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----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`your text`0NGmKSIy9Qc2tKKLNjoJRnvJ9kSSKbgqDh9lAPRX3gNG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-----END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----'''

public_key_data = b'''-----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY-----
MIIBIjANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQEFAAOCAQ8AMIIBCgKCAQEAsX6ZR0quM+PYPzni6f0E
jUGu/3ccRfJUbTfV+iaEeLF5dbbaEBy912EPGa9V6SRT4aXvEzo5KT9qrekFX9ET
LqaYaiKUy6NwswLDi8e6hhCGP+pUWhRV3dB9fYkqtKbp+WO6CWte2Y8bj2iYLAGG
xJgqg7ejwFWs6oiWNfOzGwgFlJXvRQOB9z3BOsLmjxcnOLxf1Z9GIYAxyoowQHtE
mimEDDQAOlvC0fG6EeKGRc+IZaFK9IIp1eOcT2vWO760j9UGMGNvh+S/BNrAvf8f
Ugf5+1F33S0HU0g9xZ2jfU1DQ/MClwvI7pP8GY0jvWRwETwZ49tn4DCAmjfF/0OX
qQIDAQAB
-----END PUBLIC KEY-----'''

# Load keys
private_key = rsa.PrivateKey.load_pkcs1(private_key_data)
public_key = rsa.PublicKey.load_pkcs1_openssl_pem(public_key_data)


# Message which should be signed
message = "H"
message_bytes = message.encode()
print(f'Data: {message_bytes}')

signature = rsa.sign(message_bytes, private_key, 'SHA-256')

Dart Code: (same keys)
import 'dart:convert' show utf8; 
import 'dart:convert' show base64; 
import 'dart:convert' show base64Decode; 
import 'dart:typed_data';
import 'package:encrypt/encrypt.dart' show RSAKeyParser;
import 'package:pointycastle/export.dart';
import 'dart:io'; 


 
Uint8List rsaSign(RSAPrivateKey privateKey, String dataToSign) {

  final signer = RSASigner(SHA256Digest(), '0609608648016503040201'); // 

  signer.init(true, PrivateKeyParameter<RSAPrivateKey>(privateKey)); // true=sign

  final sig = signer.generateSignature(utf8.encode(dataToSign));  

  return sig.bytes;
}

bool rsaVerify(

    RSAPublicKey publicKey, String signedData, Uint8List signature) { 
      
  final sig = RSASignature(signature);

  final verifier = RSASigner(SHA256Digest(), '0609608648016503040201'); 

  verifier.init(false, PublicKeyParameter<RSAPublicKey>(publicKey)); // false=verify

  try {
    return verifier.verifySignature(utf8.encode(signedData), sig);
  } on ArgumentError {
    return false; 
  }
}


void main() async { 

String data = "H"; 
 
final publicKeyData =  '''-----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY-----
MIIBIjANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQEFAAOCAQ8AMIIBCgKCAQEAwo3ANSEHUrMJ+M6+vEny
i+DuRisaNivtEFMhyyQ+c7iE2ooeMk33+krgK3j7A/zQ5MArOk2rHvZNFnXpcGmR
XTtcfO1d/SrQ+q3q7cjW7BJNlu4OKBWP2Y7utkbWTDrfLl66nNc46rzKqdpaYJOn
b61Wl+zjEJ5bCmfV4ZRrbgFvnkPGIaZfQuhmiBb1VLP0ZXsKvnpO1dJhX41pg9dL
0Z8xQqbFNxOn9nPbmHxO9thjsxgN3bdY2RKu2AqILj3B2XpogfL2H8wdiaMAltQ7
sjJBy5T02+x6j0ehaxGA7BI3am30YLyN3KbHOdiNvl6mwXv5NuR17DJQAsf7Nla/
9wIDAQAB
-----END PUBLIC KEY-----''';

final pubKey = RSAKeyParser().parse(publicKeyData) as RSAPublicKey;


final privateKeyData = '''-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----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-----END PRIVATE KEY-----''';

final privKey = RSAKeyParser().parse(privateKeyData) as RSAPrivateKey;

Uint8List signature = rsaSign(privKey,data); 

bool verifiedSignature = rsaVerify(pubKey, data, signature); 

if (verifiedSignature == true) {
  print("Signature successfully verified"); 
} else {
  print("Signatur could not be verified."); 
}
}


I cannot reproduce the problem: When signing with the posted Python code, the signature can be verified with the posted Dart code, provided that the private key used for signing and the public key used for verification belong together. However, it is unclear why you are posting Dart Code: (same keys), although the key pair in the Python code is obviously different from the key pair in the Dart code. By the way, there is a typo in the private key of the Python code.

So check your data. If the problem persists, edit your question, post the two signatures created with both codes (and specify which of the two keys you are using). Both signatures are identical for the same key and the same message, as both codes use PKCS#1 v1.5 padding.

Thank you! Quite embarrassing, but I think that was the thing I missed actually due to different code versions.
Thanks for your help - will check it again!
